# How to replace a specific word from a specific position of URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to replace a word from url. I have tried many code but. not working

For e.g. I have a URL : https://www.example.com/blog/single/how-to-start-single-app

Want to redirect to URL - https://www.example.com/blog/post/how-to-start-single-app

tried with the below rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)single(.*)$ $1post$2 [R=301,L]
```

but it replace all the single word of url into post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule does make sense, but you'd have to be more precise.

Either follow a strategy based on an absolute path in a rule you implement on top level:

```
RewriteRule ^/?blog/single/(.+)$ /blog/post/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or you do the same in a relative manner inside the "blog" folder:

```
RewriteRule ^single/(.+)$ post/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The important bit in both approaches is to anchor the pattern to the beginning of the subject by using the `^` special char.

I personally prefer the first strategy. If possible you should even implement such rules in the actual http server's host configuration if you have access to that. Instead of using multiple *distributed* configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using REGEX:

```
RedirectMatch  301 /old-slug/(.*) /newslug/$1
```

In your case

```
RedirectMatch  301 /blog/single/(.*) /blog/post/$1
```

Here,

(.*) is a wildcard that matches anything that appears after /old-slug/ and saves it to use in the target URL and $1 outputs the first wildcard from source URL expression.